# Reloading gifs through PHP when reloading the page

Tags: php, function, refresh, reload, gif

I am looking for a code that will reload: `thing1.gif`, `thing2.gif`... every time the user refreshes the current page. Right now the `gifs` stay on the last frame when the page refreshes but I need them to start over.

Comment: I believe that what you are looking to control is determined by the client viewing it.  You can consider using `ajax` and reloading the images into spans or divs, but I am not sure that would be reliable either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am trying to fix a broken website and don't want to re-code that much -_-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append a **`uniqid()`** to your gif image. Something like this

```
<?php
echo "<img src=thing1.gif?".uniqid();
```

This does a force reload of your image.

Comment: Do I have to pass it TRUE or should the uniqid() take care of it on it's own?

Comment: You don't have to pass anything. `uniqid()` just appends an alphanumeric text like `52602c95be3b2` to the end of your gif file. This will make the browser to reload the image again.